# Vertically center elements in WordPress header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to vertically center my header elements, but the following code that I've tried isnt working. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know where I can add padding or something else.

Here is the website: https://eagleroofingcontractor.com/

What I have so far:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <aside id="text-3" class="widget header-right widget_text">
  <div class="textwidget">
   <div class="container extra-info">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
      <div class="phone">
        <h3>631-209-7377</h3> 
<span>info@eagleroofingcontractor.com</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"> 

      <div>
       <img src="https://eagleroofingcontractor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Better-Business-Bureau-A-Logo.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"> 

      <div>
       <img src="https://eagleroofingcontractor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/gaf-master-elite-gold800px-800x292.jpg">
      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"> 

      <div>
       <img src="https://eagleroofingcontractor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Google_Partners_logo_blogpage.jpg">
      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2"> 

      <div>
       <img src="https://eagleroofingcontractor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/googole-guaranteed-min.png">
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </aside>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Which element do you need to center?

Comment: You can see all the images are on top, and the ph# is also not aligned,  https://imgur.com/a/il86bsP see this URL, the content is properly aligned, the image is photoshopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the elements **`.textwidget`**, **`.extra-info`** and the **`col-md-2`** columns inside **`.extra-info`** to flex items and then vertically center the columns using the css flex property **`align-items:center`**.

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.textwidget {
    display: flex;
}
.extra-info {
    display: flex;
}
.extra-info .col-md-2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

---

**N.B.** Your site has a lot of elements using a common ID (e.g. all your `<aside>` elements in your header uses the same `#text-3` ID).

You **should not** use the same ID for more than one elements. Replace them with a common class-name or use a different ID for each element instead.